# Has anyone coded a discord bot using mac and used ascii-table as the command handler status in terminal and it launches, but on windows it doesn't?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, ascii

so like the question poses, I coded a Discord bot using DiscordJS V13 package on my macbook via VSC and it launches just fine. The table loads, the commands all work, no "interaction failed" messages on Discord, but I'm trying to host the bot on my windows desktop and for some reason the bot doesn't turn on. It's like the table gets stuck loading and the bot is frozen, but when I switch back to my macbook, [image: Macbook Terminal] [image: Windows Desktop Terminal]

Comment: How do you expect anyone to help you when you  are not posting any code or narrowed down the problem to a specific function or action.  Start debugging -- come back

Comment: i don't think it's a code issue, which is why I didn't post any code sorry. The overall code and structure works fine on my mac, but when I compressed the folder and sent it to my windows desktop the bot no longer works, which is why I'm asking if anyone has experienced the same problem.

Comment: expect the accepted answer from Tomek is about changing your code.  So clearly you were wrong when you told me it was not about code @senpai.  (Not very senpai of you.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you show your code, so I can see what's wrong with it? But maybe you have in code `` (await PG(`${process.cwd()}/Commands/*/*.js`)) `` or something similar? if yes replace it with this: `` (await PG(`${(process.cwd().replace(/\\/g, "/"))}/Commands/*/*.js`)) ``. Then everything should be fine.

Comment: (await PG(`${process.cwd()}/Events/*/*.js`)).map(async (file) => {
        const event = require(file); is what I have

Comment: This is the full code of my event.js ```const { Events } = require("../Validation/EventNames");

module.exports = async (client, PG, Ascii) => {
    const Table = new Ascii("Events Loaded");

    (await PG(`${process.cwd()}/Events/*/*.js`)).map(async (file) => {
        const event = require(file);

        if(!Events.includes(event.name) || !event.name) {
            const L = file.split("/");
            await Table.addRow(`${event.name} || "MISSING}`, `⛔ Event name is either invalid or missing: ${L[6] +`/` + L[7]}`);
            return;
        }```

Comment: so replace it with: ```(await PG(`${(process.cwd().replace(/\\/g, "/"))}/Events/*/*.js`))```

Comment: instead ```(await PG(${process.cwd()}/Events/*/*.js))```

Comment: if it doesnt work, try just add ```.replace(/\\/g, "/")``` after ```{process.cwd()}```

Comment: thank you so much! mind telling me why it didn't work? for future reference

Comment: Instead of just dumping some code, please provide the explanation behind the answer